# Make a control for slideshow

Tags: jquery

I'll try to make a control box for this slideshow, but doesn't work perfectly, what's the problem?

See my code:

**jquery:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
           .next('img').fadeIn()
           .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    },
      5000);

    $('#1').click(function () {
        $('.fadein img:gt(0').show();
    });

    $('#2').click(function () {
        $('.fadein img:gt(1)').show();
    });

    $('#3').click(function () {
        $('.fadein img:gt(2)').show();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pedram68/cRvya/6/)

Comment: `$('.fadein img:gt(0').show();` change it to `$('.fadein img:gt(0)').show();`

Answer (score 0):

`$('.fadein img:gt(0')` should be `$('.fadein img:gt(0)')`

Comment: Hm... I think your code needs some more work, but I'm too tired to do it now. As far as I can tell, you'll need to hide the other images when you show the new image using the control.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to hide other images, but if couldn't , will waiting for you'r answer. thanks